# How to connect LDAP With username and password?

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

I have my Ldap working the only issue i'm facing was when I try to login with email that is when I land in the else part in the below code. If my username is different from email then it throws error. i.e if my email is 'skumar@gmail.com' and my username is 'saurakumar' then it will through invalid username password error.
As internally I'm using username to make email i.e if the user login with name 'karan' then i'm expecting the email to be karan @gmail.com which is not true in many scenario and the Authentication fails. I'm looking for some solution wherein I can login either via email or via username I'll be able to authenticate user. Below is the snippet of my code. Please suggest?

```
    ldapEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, initialContextFactory);
    ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    ldapEnv.remove(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL);
    if (email == null) {
        lContext = new InitialLdapContext(ldapEnv, null);
        entryResult = searchUserEntry(lContext, user, searchCtrls);
        final String usrDN = ((Context) entryResult.getObject()).getNameInNamespace();

        lContext.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        lContext.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, usrDN);
        lContext.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pass);
        lContext.reconnect(null);
    } else {
            ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, email);
            ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, credentials);
            lContext = new InitialLdapContext(ldapEnv, null);
            return lContext;
        searchUserEntry(lContext, user, searchCtrls);
    }
```

Comment: Does this help: https://bitbucket.org/jwilleke/examples/src/35a41cfee32519650f12dafbc008b01895a3cf29/Examples-JNDI/src/com/willeke/samples/ldap/jndi/BasicAdminSearchBind.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: You're passing an e-mail value to the ```Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL``` property which should in fact be holding the bind DN for the user.

Comment: @Bora How can get the bind DN in this case ?

Comment: @Saurabh I'm not sure if I understand your code logic, but you get the DN of the entry whose (probably) ```mail``` attribute is equal to the value of ```email```.  You seem to be doing this in the ```if (email == null) {``` block for ```user``` and storing DN in ```usrDN```.

Comment: @Bora that is for Simple Authentication. I'm facing issues in the else part when the Authentication is not Simple and if i try to search for userDN like the way I did in the IF block I get an error that it has to be binded first.

Comment: What is the authentication method? SASL? Can you show what you're doing in the ```checkMultiLevelAuthIdentity``` method?

Comment: @Bora that method I have placed it by mistake now I have removed it from this post. You are absolutely right that putting DN value allowed me to login. But I have tried putting the DN value manually. What I wanted to know now how will I get the DN value. Is it possible to obtain it only on the basis of username or not (keeping in mind that we have non anonymous binding).

Comment: Then, you may want to create an entry in the directory which you can use as a/n application/functional ID whose DN and password you'd use to bind to the directory first and to search for the user (email) to get its DN for the authentication.

Comment: @EJP I didn't suggest to use a third attribute. ```email``` is the variable the OP has in its code that references the user, who apparently is identified by their e-mail address, which is probably stored in the existing attribute mail.

Comment: @Bora So you are suggesting what I had already said in my answer?

Comment: @EJP I've been trying to get to the same through comments before you actually submitted your answer. I was trying to understand what the OP really wanted and what his code excerpt sort of alluded to in terms how their directory was set up. He already seems to be doing what we both tried to describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this is a 3-step process:

1. Bind to LDAP as an administrative user. Note that this should not be the master user defined in the configuration file: that's for OpenLDAP's use itself. Instead it should be a user mentioned in the DIT that has the appropriate search access for the next step.
2. Search for the user via some unique attribute, e.g. in your case email.
3. Using the found DN of the user and the password he specified, attempt to bind as that user (with the `reconnect()` method, after changing the environment of the context appropriately).

If all that succeeds, you have a login success. If (2) or (3) fail, you have a failure, and note that you should not tell the user which it was: otherwise you are leaking information to attackers. You should not mention whether it was the username (email) or the password that was wrong.